# How to create and output data as links?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a web form, where I can insert articles to the database, using a text editor.  my article table has the following  fieldnames; id, title, content, type and uploadDate.  The 'content' fieldname is composed of text.  This text also involves data from another database table, called tag (i.e. tag_id, name, type), which is not linked to the article table.

when I view the articles on the webform, they look like as the following output:

```
Pellentesque eget elit tag1. Vivamus ut lacinia lectus. Mauris eu efficitur mi. 
Nam blandit est ut justo scelerisque, in sagittis nibh scelerisque. 
tag2 placerat id risus ut aliquam. Vestibulum maximus rutrum arcu et sagittis.
```

My question, is how can I make my article's content to look like the desired output below:

```
Pellentesque eget elit ***tag1***. Vivamus ut lacinia lectus. Mauris eu efficitur mi. 
Duis placerat id risus ut aliquam. Vestibulum maximus rutrum arcu et sagittis.  
***tag2*** id consequat dui. Suspendisse non imperdiet odio.
```

Showing, tag's name (`tag1` & `tag2`) as links, within the content of the article.  The links would be composed of some sort of querystring, when clicked, it renders to a webpage, which holds that tag's id record (via DataTable).

I am aware, this approach, would require me to create hyperlinks for the tag's name, but I am not quite sure, how would I go about, creating this dynamically (i.e. set ALL instances of [tag1, tag2] as hyperlinks). Would I need to create this task, in the insert method of article or getData() method of my aricle?

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Many thanks

Comment: Not a complete answer, but to start with you need a rich text box instead of a standard text box.

Comment: I am using tinymce text editor to insert articles into my database, is this what you are suggesting.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unsure whether you the articles to be editable with the links clickable in the textbox itself. I've assumed not, and that this is a view page for existing articles.

If that's the case there are many ways to do this, personally I'd recommend using a [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{     
    var ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    string html = this.GetArticleText();

    // create the html formatted HTML/Links taking into account anti-xss attacks
    foreach(var tag in this.LoadAllTags())
    {
      html.Replace(tag.Key, this.CreateLinkHtml(tag);
    }

    ctrl.InnerHtml = html;

    this.SomePageContainer.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  this is a great starting point.  I would like to ask one last question, is that where would I place this logic, inside my insert() method or create a new method and link it both `insert()` & `getArticle()` method. Many thanks.

Comment: @user3070072 I've edited my answer - personally I would put this in the OnPreRender section. That way it's called after any events you may add later. Obviously you'll need to add GetArticleText(), LoadAllTags() and CreateLinkHtml() methods yourself.

Comment: Ah...this is starting to make a lot more sense.  Thank you so much for your time and support.  Is the purpose of `LoadAllTags()`method - to call all the tag's name from the tags database?  if so, I have more than 150,000 records...would that be okay? please advice further. Thanks

Comment: @user3070072 you may want to filter that... however get it working then optimise later if required. The original idea was for that method to load all tags in from the database. My suggestion would be to associate tags when creating the articles with some sort of link table, it will take longer to save but generally articles are viewed more than they're edited.

Comment: @user3070072 no worries!